# Why Spark preserves - Shuffle Intermediate files in case of RDD but not Dataset

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark

In case multiple actions on base dataset - why spark recomputes whole lineage but this is not case for RDD.

https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/rdd-programming-guide.html#performance-impact

"Shuffle also generates a large number of intermediate files on disk. As of Spark 1.3, these files are preserved until the corresponding RDDs are no longer used and are garbage collected. This is done so the shuffle files don’t need to be re-created if the lineage is re-computed. Garbage collection may happen only after a long period of time, if the application retains references to these RDDs or if GC does not kick in frequently. This means that long-running Spark jobs may consume a large amount of disk space. The temporary storage directory is specified by the spark.local.dir configuration parameter when configuring the Spark context."

Due to this - RDD performs better in case multiple of actions (without need of Cache or induced action) while Dataset needs special handling.

Need help in understanding.

Looking for option to have same feature in case Dataset, Temporary conversion Of Dataset to RDD and Again back Dataset provides same benefit.

```
Dataset<Long> rangeDs = session.range(0L, 2000000L);
Dataset<Tuple2<Long,Long>> rangePairDsGbk =  rangeDs.groupByKey(new 
MapFunction<Long, Long>(){

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Override
public Long call(Long value) throws Exception {
    return value;
}
}, Encoders.LONG()).reduceGroups(new ReduceFunction<Long>() {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Override
public Long call(Long v1, Long v2) throws Exception {
    return 1L;
}
});
rangePairDsGbk.count(); //Full Re-Computation
rangePairDsGbk.count();//Full Re-Computation (why this job is doing Full Re- 
computation)

JavaRDD<Long> rangeRdd = session.range(0L, 2000000L).toJavaRDD();
JavaPairRDD<Long, Long> rangePairRddRbk = rangeRdd.mapToPair(new 
PairFunction<Long, Long, Long>() {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Override
public Tuple2<Long, Long> call(Long t) throws Exception {
    return new Tuple2<Long, Long>(t, t);
}
}).reduceByKey(new Function2<Long, Long, Long>() {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Override
public Long call(Long v1, Long v2) throws Exception {
    return 1L;
}
}, 200);
rangePairRddRbk.count();//Full Re-Computation
rangePairRddRbk.count();//Partial Re-Computation (Only Shuffle Read as 
Expected)
```